# How do I parse data points in numpy array python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parsing

I have a numpy array with shape (100,100). It has values in it like -.320+0.323i. How do I separate this into two separate numpy arrays, one with the real values and one with the "i" values?

Comment: Did you try to web search this? The "i" values are called imaginary part (without the "I" itself). [This](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.real.html?highlight=real#numpy.ndarray.real) will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in functions .real and .imag like this:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 1.+0.j])
realparts = a.real
imagparts = a.imag
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a numpy array called arr.

```
import numpy as np
#Example numpy array with real and imaginary parts
arr = np.array([1, 2 + 3j, 3, 4 + 6j, 5 + 9j, 6])
print(arr.imag) #Prints imaginary parts of arr
print(arr.real) #Prints real parts of arr
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

simply use these 2 lines:

```
# Assume A is the numpy.array
>>> A.real
>>> A.imag
```